# Laravel get all with same id

Tags: laravel, show

I have a table with category_id. Category_id can has 1,2,3 or 4 as a value. Now I want to show all results with value 1. How do i do it in this code? Thanks.

```
public function getshopGSM()
{
    $shopGSM = new Product();
    $shopGSM = Product::all();
    return view('eindwerk.shopGSM', [
        'shopGSM' => $shopGSM
    ]);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public function getshopGSM()
{
    $shopGSM = Product::where('category_id', 1)->get();
    return view('eindwerk.shopGSM', [
        'shopGSM' => $shopGSM
    ]);
}
```

Comment: It works, simple question. But i'm learning step by step! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

try like this:

```
public function getshopGSM()
    {
        $shopGSM = Product::where('category_id', 1)->get();
        return view('eindwerk.shopGSM', compact('shopGSM '));
    }
```

You must select all products WHERE category_id is 1, and you need insert ->get() because you need get all results.

```
if you want select only one you can use ->first()
```

also you can you can select products and give them a ORDER, you can use

```
Product::orderBy('id','desc')->where('category_id', 1)->get();
```